# Coffeescript - Why are my class's attributes undefined onclick?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a simple class, box:

```
class Box
    constructor: (@idx, grid) ->
        console.log("constructing", @idx)
        @elem = document.createElement("div")
        @elem.id = "box" + idx
        @elem.className = "box"
        @elem.onclick = @toggle
        grid.appendChild(@elem)

    toggle: () ->
        alert("click")
        console.log("My idx is: ", @idx)
```

When the constructor runs it reports "constructing 0", "constructing 1" etc so I know the class attribute is being defined. And if I call b.toggle() (where b is a box instance) then it reports the idx properly. But once I click on the element on the page it says that @idx is undefined.

So it seems like somehow the box's attributes are lost in the onclick side of things. Why is this?

Here's the compiled Javascript:

```
Box = (function() {

  function Box(idx, grid) {
    this.idx = idx;
    console.log("constructing", this.idx);
    this.elem = document.createElement("div");
    this.elem.id = "box" + idx;
    this.elem.className = "box";
    this.elem.onclick = this.toggle;
    grid.appendChild(this.elem);
  }

  Box.prototype.toggle = function() {
    alert("click");
    return console.log("My idx is: ", this.idx);
  };

  return Box;

})();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) for `toggle` method definition to bind it to the right context (your class instance in this case):

```
toggle: =>
  alert("click")
  console.log("My idx is: ", @idx)
```

Answer (score 4):

nl_0 has good answer for the solution. But on the javascript end of things, here is why this did not work out very well.

The `Box` function which constructs `Box` objects attaches the `toggle` prototype function to the element with this line of code:

```
this.elem.onclick = this.toggle;
```

As a result, when inside of the function `toggle`, all that is accessible is the element that the event is attached to. Thus, `this` inside of `toggle` is `elem`, and that is why you cannot see `.idx` on it.

Comment: @danmane - HTMLElement does not have a defined property `this`. In order for `this`'s scope to be the same as `Box` in that sense then the function would have had to have been defined in the constructor, and `this` would have to be cached in a variable usually named `self`.